# Looping through an array and observable in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop

I have an observable that I am getting back from my service that has a nested array value. I want to push all the class costs out into a new, separate array. How do I go about this?

Student
First_name
Last_name
Class[
Class_name
Class_cost
]

The best I can do is

```
  this.classCostData = []
     this.classCostData.push(this.students$.subscribe(data => data.map(student => student.class_cost.forEach(class => this.classCostData.push(class.class_cost)))))
```

When I print the value of that, I get an array, but it says [Safesubscriber] and I cannot access the values

Comment: Get rid of that outer push call

Comment: When I get rid of the Outer Push, my print results in 0

Comment: Your code inside the subscribe is wrong too. `map` returns a new array. You can simply assign `this.classCostData=data.map(student=> student.class_cost)` or if you want to keep pushing instead of resetting the global array, change your `forEach` to `forEach(cost => this.classCostData.push(cost);`

Comment: "Student First_name Last_name Class[ Class_name Class_cost ]"

Can you create a type definition for this? Or at least give an example data.

Answer (score 0):

Your datastructure is a bit unclear for me, however I created an example that should help make things clear.

- First of all: you should use rxjs pipe with map operators. This will
  help make things much cleaner going forward.
- Second: you should only subscribe if absolutely necessary. (memory
  leaks & more)
- 

```
let students$ = of([
  { firstName: "egbert", class: [10, 15, 20] },
  { firstName: "cobal", class: [60, 80] }
]);


students$
  .pipe(
    map((data) => data.map((student) => student.class)),
    map((multiDimArray: number[][]) => [].concat(...multiDimArray))
  )
  .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

First in the pipe we map the data to only get the class array. Then we "flatten" the array so we have 1 array with all prices.